# deleting btrfs subvolume: any difference between "btrfs subvolume delete" and "rm -rf"?

Tags: linux, btrfs

as the title says, when deleting a btrfs subvolume, is there any reason to use the "proper" `btrfs subvolume delete`-command instead of just rm -rf ?

(i assume the `btrfs subvolume` command is faster given that *presumably* it doesn't have to recursively delete all files/folders it contains first, but is there any other difference than speed?)

Comment: ... not sure if i should ask this on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com tho, any opinions there?

Comment: The [man page](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume) seems to indicate it is for speed "*The corresponding directory is removed instantly but the data blocks are removed later in the background. The command returns immediatelly*".  Don't know if there is any other difference though.

Comment: @lx07: link died =(

Comment: @EugenKonkov - they do alas. still here though : https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/btrfs-subvolume.8.html